# Net install (mini.iso) via USB

Tags: grub2, 14.04, usb, ubuntu-minimal

I'm trying to do a net install of Ubuntu 14.04 using mini.iso by following the instructions from [Ubuntu Installation Minimal CD Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

```
64-bit PC (amd64, x86_64)
Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" Minimal CD 37MB* 
(MD5: 7297321c2fa6424417a548c85edd6e98, SHA1: e1e074b4302898698977c08013e0afe5c06245e2)
```

On the site, it says:

New: You can make a working USB install drive with the dd cloning method with mini.iso version 13.04. See this link and this tutorial.

So I `dd`'ed the image to a USB drive and the installer boots up fine. As I proceed through the installation, I get this error message:

```
----
[!!] Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk

Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.

This is a fatal error.
----
```

I noticed when I was creating the partitions for the hard drive, I got this screen:

```
[!!] Partition disks  
Note that all data on the disk you select will be erased, but not before you have confirmed that you really want to make the changes:
Select the disk to partition:
SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 15.6 GB STT DATA GUARDIAN
SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdb) - 250.1 GB ATA 
----
```

Obviously, I want to install to my hard drive so I chose SCSI3 (sdb).  It seems that the installer assumes that the hard drive is `/dev/sda` but since there is a USB key, it uses `sda` and GRUB fails to install.  This is just my theory, but I'm not sure.

Note that I am doing a clean install with no other partitions.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The installer usually assumes it is correct to use /dev/sda for installing grub. It isn't in you case, so change it to /dev/sdb.

Comment: Thank you @mikewhatever.  How do you change it?  I am going through the installer.  I can't seem to change that...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not installing this on a UEFI system you should run the following command to install grub on your /dev/sdb: sudo update-grub /dev/sdb

Then reboot! Let us know if it works.

(BTW: Are you trying to install this on a UEFI system? Why do I ask? Because I have always got grub installation error messages everytime I have tried to install X/Ubuntu on a UEFI system without allowing system updates at install time. Just saying.)

Comment: Thanks but I'm in the middle of the installer and do not have access to a shell...  Also I am on a uefi system (intel motherboard s1600jp2)

Comment: Here is my suggestion: till you have STRONG reasons to stick with mini iso ... dont! Just use a regular Ubuntu iso and run with it. Just FYI: I use Xubuntu. At install time, Xubuntu gives the option to update the system by downloading packages from the server. If I choose to update the system at install time then Xubuntu install works fine. But, if I choose to NOT update the system at install time then Xubuntu croaks AT THE END OF THE INSTALLATION. Specifically it's a grub error. So, use a regular ISO img and update at install time.